# Dominated convergence theorem for vairance and cesaro mean of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, cesaro-summable

I was wondering the following problem:

If $X_n$ is a sequence of independent random variables, $|X_n|\leq b, (b>0)$ and $X_n$ converges to $X$ almost surely. Using dominated convergence theorem, we have $\mathbb{E}[\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n] = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n] = \mathbb{E}[X]$. Similarly, we have $\mathbb{E}[\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n^2] = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]$. Therefore, we have $Var(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Var(X_n) = Var(X)$

Then, using cesaro sum we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum^n_{i=1} X_i}{n} = X$ almost surely. So, $Var(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum^n_{i=1} X_i}{n}) = Var(X) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Var(\frac{\sum^n_{i=1} X_i}{n}) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}Var(\sum^n_{i=1} X_i) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}Var(X_i)}{n^2} $.

On the other hand, using cesaro sum for the sequence $Var(X_n)$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}Var(X_i)}{n} = Var(X)$. Combine with the previous results, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}Var(X_i)}{n} = Var(X)= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}Var(X_i)}{n^2}$.

This is obviously not correct, but I don't know where went wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider $X_n$ identically distributed. Now, it can be seen that the claim about the Cesaro means for the random variables is false. The issue is that when we are taking the sum, the probability space to the product space.

Comment: @AbhishekShetty Could you elaborate is a bit? why does it turn into a product space?

Comment: @AbhishekShetty is the cesaro means for r.v. not true or is the variance part not true?

Comment: @AbhishekShetty ok, i see. So in general we don't have $\frac{\sum^n_1X_i(\omega)}{n} = \frac{(\sum^n_1X_i)(\omega))}{n} $

Comment: As an illustrative example, take $X_n \sim Bern(0.5)$. With this you can see that how the probabilities behave. Think of how $\sum X_i $  is "generated". What we need is to "draw" $\omega_i$ and then evaluate $X_i( \omega_i) $ and sum as opposed to "draw" $ \omega$ and then evaluate  $\sum X_i  ( \omega)$.

Comment: What you describe in the last comment, is true by definition if we view them as functions from $ \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ but the interpretation is a bit different as we are summing "independent" versions instead of versions lying in the same probability space.

Comment: @AbhishekShetty but in the bernoulli case, $X_n$ does not converge to anything

Comment: If we take them on the same space, $X_n$ converges to $Bern(0.5)$ right? But, if we take independent copies, they lie on different spaces.